# Cocoa app - can I integrate Amazon Product search within my cocoa app

Tags: cocoa, amazon-product-api

I have integrated Amazon Product Search using the widgets they provide within my website. I also want to integrate it within my cocoa app.

Any idea how this can be done? Do they have an API/web service which we can use in the cocoa app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Do they have an API/web service which we can use in the cocoa app?

Yes. [Delicious Library](http://delicious-monster.com/) uses it. I think [this is the one](https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/advertising/api/detail/main.html), although I could be wrong.

Note that you can't use this if your Cocoa app shares the data with a Cocoa Touch counterpart. [Delicious Monster had to discontinue their Library iPhone app after Amazon changed their terms of service](http://quatermain.tumblr.com/post/137216252/amazon-axes-delicious-library-for-iphone) to forbid API users (e.g., Delicious Monster, you) from sending data obtained through the API to an iPhone.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the post about the licensing issue: saved me a lot of wasted effort. +1

Answer (score 0):

You can create an HTML frame for the gadget and embed it in the Cocoa app using [`UIWebView`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) on the iPhone, or using [`WebView`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Classes/WebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) on the desktop side.

Assuming that you stored the `HTML` required for presenting the gadget in `htmlSnippet`, and have already setup a `WebView`, you can simply load it via:

```
[[webView mainFrame] loadHTMLString:htmlSnippet baseURL:someURL];
```

(Where someURL is used to resolve relative URLs in the HTML source.)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few wrappers over this Amazon API for Python and Ruby, which you could integrate into you app using PyObjC or MacRuby. This may be a faster way to implement this instead of having to roll your own Objective-C layer over these web service calls.